# What is the canonicity of "Arcane"?

Tags: arcane

The new series *Arcane* involves a number of characters and settings from *League of Legends*. Online sources, including the fan wikis, variously claim that the series is:

- Completely compatible with the current lore, and intended to serve as an origin story for several characters (the tagline of the show would seem to indicate this).
- Contradictory with the current lore, but intended to replace it from here on out: that is, the games will adopt the canon of the show when it conflicts with previous stories.
- Intended to take place in a different, separate, continuity, whether it is currently compatible with the lore or not.

Which of these is correct? What is the canonicity of the show relative to the games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Arcane is Canon

**Arcane’s creators have confirmed this**
[In interview](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ungeek.ph/2021/11/full-interview-arcane-creators-christian-linke-and-alex-yee-on-the-new-league-of-legends-animated-series/%3famp), Christian Linke & Alex Yee noted:

> So, does this mean Arcane is canon? Or is the League of Legends canon a bit more fluid in that regard?
> **Alex:** We’re doing the best that we can **to make sure that Arcane is internally consistent and is canon.** But at this point, I don’t think we would be considered a source of truth over the game. I do think though this is the first time for us to dive into something like this. So, our goal is really to listen to fans, see how they feel about it, and then and use what we learned to try and continue delivering the best experience we can.

**League of Legends’ design team has confirmed the games will be including Arcane characters in future**

[In recent Reddit Q/A](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/oghjo6/riots_mission_to_advance_the_lore_with_the/hm2ojao/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf&context=3), Lead Champion Producer Ryan “Reav3” Mireles confirmed that League of Legends’ design team has started discussing the idea of adding Arcane’s characters to League of Legends. He said:

> “With how much Arcane has resonated with so many players and viewers, the Champs team is definitely excited to explore characters from Arcane as long as they actually make sense in our MOBA setting.”

Comment: I don't think that's conclusive. "We are doing our best to be consistent" and "we will explore ideas from Arcane" is very different from "Yes, it is canon". For example, I can do my best to make a Harry Potter fanfiction that is consistent with the existing canon, but it would not be canon. And Mireles' answer only say that they may borrow some ideas from the series for the game ("as long as they make sense in our MOBA setting"). Short of a statement from Riot Games, this is at best a lower level of canon.

Comment: Not quite a good example. You’re not JK Rowling’s licensed creator though, and they’re not you or making a “Harry Potter fan fiction.” 

Comment: if being a licensed creator was sufficient, there would be no question... ask the creators of Star Wars Legend books and Netflix's Marvel shows.

Comment: I don’t need to ask them because I can read those Legends books or watch Netflix’s Marvel shows and experience the story they’re telling.

Comment: Sure, have fun! Daredevil and Punisher are great for example. But being great and enjoyable does not make them canon. On the contrary, the MCU execs' decisions on what is canon or not does.

Comment: Right. So what makes you believe Riot Games execs aren’t making Arcane’s creators do the best that they can to make sure that Arcane is internally consistent and is canon?

Comment: Because there is no official word from them and this website is not about what we or the creators believe... did you expect the creators to say something like "we didn't care about the lore and what players expected and just did whatever we wanted"?

Comment: “No official word from them.” So you don’t believe integration of Arcane by Riot into Riot’s game isn’t any sort of statement?

Comment: Something like "Maybe we will incorporate some elements from the show to the game" is far from an affirmation that the show is canon.